# Cannot use boto2 to assign qualification to Mechanical Turkers

Tags: python-3.x, boto, mechanicalturk

I am trying to assign a qualification I created to Turkers who completed an experiment of mine, using boto2. I have three batches of the same experiment (each has a different HIT ID). I easily assigned the qualification to the first batch, with this code:

```
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection
mturk = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,
                    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                    host=HOST)
qualificationID = 'qualificationIDString'
for worker_id in workerIDList:
    #   assign qualification
    print("Granting qualification: %s to worker %s"%(globLoc_qualification, worker_id))
    mturk.assign_qualification(qualification_type_id=qualificationID, 
                                         worker_id=worker_id)
```

I then changed the HIT ID to the second batch and rerun the same code but with time, I get the error:

```
Granting qualification: 3HWVT555HSXFC1HZE98Y23F1CFJAI3 to worker: A1ZTSCPETU3UJW
MTurkRequestError: 200 OK
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AssignQualificationResponse><OperationRequest><RequestId>ede118ea-9440-4a4d-8f9b-94b816c3a92f</RequestId></OperationRequest><AssignQualificationResult><Request><IsValid>False</IsValid><Errors><Error><Code>AWS.MechanicalTurk.QualificationAlreadyExists</Code><Message>The qualification already exists. (1531770857498)</Message></Error></Errors></Request></AssignQualificationResult></AssignQualificationResponse> A1ZTSCPETU3UJW
```

Any hint on what does 'Qualification already exist' refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying *The Worker you're trying to grant QualificationType to already has that Qualification*.  You're likely seeing this because granting a QualificationType is something that happens on a Worker, not a HIT. A Worker can have the Qualification, or not. The Worker can't have it multiple times.

For more information on Qualifications and QualificationTypes, check out these resources:

1. https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-understanding-requirements-and-qualifications-99a26069fba2
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/Concepts_QualificationsArticle.html